# Spring Boot 2.0.5 can not bind list of properties from spring-cloud-config server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-config

I've run into a next situation: I've migrated my application from Spring Boot 1.5.x
to Spring Boot 2.0.5.

I have the next class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "some.property")
public class Myclass {

@Getter
@Setter
private List<String> list;

}
```

Also I have yml config like this:

```
some:
  property:
    list:
      - value 1
      - value 2
      - value 3
```

This config is fetched from remote spring-cloud-config server.

If I try to run application I have next exception:

```
org.springframework.boot.
context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 
'some.property' to Myclass


Description:

Property: some.property.list[0]
Value: value 1
Origin: "some.property.list[0]" from property source "bootstrapProperties"
Reason: The elements 
[some.property.list[0],some.property.list[1],some.property.list[2]] were 
left unbound.
   Property: some.property.list[1]
Value: value 2
Origin: "some.property.list[1]" from property source "bootstrapProperties"
Reason: The elements 
[some.property.list[0],some.property.list[1],some.property.list[2]] were 
left unbound.

Property: some.property.list[2]
Value: value 3
Origin: "some.property.list[2]" from property source "bootstrapProperties"
Reason: The elements 
[some.property.list[0],some.property.list[1],some.property.list[2]] were 
left unbound.
```

But if I use local bootstrap.yml file not remote config server - everything is fine.

Has anybody run in to the same problem ? I really need your help.

P.S. Spring config server has version 2.0.5 too.

Comment: It seems you have omitted the $ and curly braces {}. You should declared like this : @Value("${some.property.list}")

Comment: Ebert Toribio, I've made a mistake in a example above, actually I use @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "some.property"). Sorry for this.

Comment: Do you have the same problem?

Comment: Yap, problem is the same as above.

Comment: Could you put your properties by this way : Value1, Value2, Value3. As I can see you are listing values but you need separate them by comma in the same line

Comment: Ebert Toribio, thank you for you attention. I've found root cause, it is in the comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found a root cause of the problem.

Well, because I am not super experienced guy with Cloud Config Server the reason were hard to find. It is all about overriding property list for different profiles:

Let's imagine you have two property files on you config server:

application.yml

application-dev.yml - it has higher priority, so it overrides everything that was before it.

In application.yml I've had property like this

```
some:
  property:
    list:
```

So, this is just empty list.

But in application-dev.yml I've had property like this:

```
some:
  property:
    list:
      - value 1
      - value 2
      - value 3
```

So, in this situation you will get error like I've mentioned above. 
All you need to do - fix empty list like this.

```
some:
  property:
    list:
      - ""
```